# Dice differences, theoretical probability and expected values

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm sure there's lots of different stories around to explain the same problem but here's the situation.

You have to put 9 prisoners into 5 or less cells.

Cell 0 / Cell 1/ Cell 2/ Cell 3/Cell 4/Cell 5

Every day two dice are rolled and the dice difference determines from which cell 1 prisoner is released, the process is then repeated.

From drawing the possibility space for two dice, and running simulations it’s possible to get some good strategies for releasing the prisoners in the least number of days but how could one go about 
calculating either,

The expected value for the number of days required for a given starting configuration

OR

alternatively, a measure of the theoretical probability of one configuration beating another starting configuration in minimizing the number of days required?

Comment: I see there's no takers, but I've got a little further. I think I can reduce the problem down to a multinomial distribution.  Using geometric distribution element of the last prisoner being released on the last day and the product of the probabilities of all prisoners being released on a certain number of days multiplied by the number of days the infinite summation leads to the expected value for the number of days of required for a given configuration.  I can see it but it will take a little time to write-up but it still leaves me with an infinite summation of a relatively complex expression

Answer (score 1):

Cliff, I find this problem very interesting! Where did you get this problem? Are there other versions of the problem?

Comment: I first saw the problem as part of the Maths300 tasks (http://www.maths300.com/) which is a series of different rich tasks for school students but that are open-ended enough to be approached at a number of levels.

Comment: I just accessed maths300.com and got the following piece of info: "Dice Differences (Prisoners) Probability, Statistics, Number 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9" which says the original problem is for students of years 3-9, so must not be as difficult as this one you posted here, Cliff. I guess you modified the original problem and hence the problem you posted here is really a new one not appeared anywhere else?

Comment: I like this problem as it poses great challenges in probability theories and computing skills, and I learned new skills through the process of theoretically analysing it and numerically computing the expected number of days to release all prisoners. For example, I feel it's amazing that I'm able to get the optimal allocation when there are 90 prisoners.

Answer (score 0):

My computer program outputs these:

- at [1 4 2 1 1 0] the expected number of days is 19.0 days which is the lowest for $N=9$
- at [3 6 5 3 1 0] 31.5 days the lowest for $N=18$
- at [4 8 6 4 2 0] 39.6 days the lowest for $N=24$
- and for $N=36$ at [6 10 8 6 4 2] the expected number of days is 59.15 days, which is not the shortest
- at [6 11 9 6 3 1] 55.26 days is the shortest for $N=36$.

Comment: One difficulty is on some days some cells are empty and hence possibly no prisoner to be released. By the way, my computer program went further: at [9 17 13 9 5 1] the mean number of days is 77.2 days which is the shortest for N=54.